# setting of anroid:priority attribute does not work for sample applications installed by me

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to figure out why I get a resolver activity if i have more than one intent-filter for the same action although I have prioritised them as 50 and 10. 
Also I do not get any resolver activity if I make any of the priorities as negative. Also the filters do get prioritised and the one that has a positive priority receives the intent.

Any help on this behaviour of the intent filters would be appreciated.

Thanks.